# How to prevent log message "skipping setting already-present value for key"

Tags: nsuserdefaults, synchronized, xcode8

When storing values in `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myValue forKey:@"myKey"];
```

... if value was already existing, Xcode 8 will log:

> 2016-07-14 09:59:04.081806 MyAppName[52232:2561291] [User Defaults] CFPrefsPlistSource<0x7941d950> (Domain: com.myAppBundle, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null)) skipping setting already-present value for key myKey

1) Can I ask Xcode to not log this? *[main question]*

2) Or should I compare equality of previously stored values before using `setValue:forKey:`? *[subsidiary question]*

Example:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myKey"] isEqual:myValue])
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myValue forKey:@"myKey"];
```

3) Or should I perform this compare with a thread-safe lock to avoid storing twice the same value between the instruction where I compare and the instruction where I use `setValue:forKey:`? *[subsidiary question]*

Example:

```
@synchronized ([NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]) {
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"myKey"] isEqual:myValue])
        [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:myValue forKey:@"myKey"];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with Beta 1 and Beta 2 only. Fixed with Xcode 8 beta 3:

> When debugging applications in the Simulator, the OS will not produce an excessive amount of
>   unhelpful logging. (26652255)

Also, more logging can be removed by editing each scheme and adding a specific environment variable, `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` to `disable`:
[image: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE disable]